# how to open file that I have partial of its name and read its lines in c#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, file-io

I wrote the following lines to read a file in c# and get its contents and then store them in an array. The problem is that I can not have the full name of the file i.e. I have partial of its name as follows:

```
string[] lines3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(
    "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Rounds/Fitness/AUV1/paths/"0.1152370.txt");

int cnt4 = 0;    
bestPathL3 = new float[lines3.Length, 2];

foreach (string line in lines3)    
{
    string[] temp = line.Split(' ');
    bestPathL3[cnt4, 0] = (float)double.Parse(temp[0]);
    bestPathL3[cnt4, 1] = (float)double.Parse(temp[1]);
    cnt4++;
}
```

**BUT**, the file name is 0.115237052475505 as example...

Comment: So you want to modify a file without knowing the file name?

Comment: If you only have partial file name, how do you know then that you are reading the right file? You could have two files with those same numbers in the file name, but have different numbers after "0.1152370"

Comment: Sounds like you need to get the file name first.  Try the overload of [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a search pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate the files which their names contains your `partialName`. So, try to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and apply search pattern with linq `where` clause actions.

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.Contains("partialFileName"));
int cnt4 = 0;
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var lines3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    bestPathL3 = new float[lines3.Length, 2];
    foreach (string line in lines3)
    {
        string[] temp = line.Split(' ');
        bestPathL3[cnt4, 0] = (float)double.Parse(temp[0]);
        bestPathL3[cnt4, 1] = (float)double.Parse(temp[1]);
        cnt4++;
        //Do something with bestPathL3
    }
}
```